# Error reading image xxx

Tags: liferay, upgrade

After upgrading from Liferay 6.0.6 to 6.1 and transfer of all the document library files to the database through jackrabbit, I can't see the images on the site any more. I get these kinds of errors:

```
ERROR [ImageImpl:66] Error reading image 13399    
    com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.NoSuchFileException: {fileName=13399.jpg, versionLabel=}
    at com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.store.JCRStore.getFileContentNode(JCRStore.java:886)
    at com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.store.JCRStore.getFileAsStream(JCRStore.java:441)
    at com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.store.BaseStore.getFileAsStream(BaseStore.java:354)
```

I read somewhere that it might be a permission related error, but I checked the permission related configurations and they are the same as in the previous version. Any idea what this is about? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nope unfortunately. Still fighting with it.